# nginx container 80 port redirect to a non configured url

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have strated a nginx container in my linux mahince to do some test. After some test, I want to comment the code in "location /quince-builds" and expect that I could get other configurations works. However, every uri redirects to a url with "/quince-builds". For example, when I request http://192.168.39.7/myrtle-builds. It shows http://192.168.39.7/myrtle-builds/quince-builds not found.
And when I request http://192.168.39.7. It shows http://192.168.39.7/quince-builds.

I shuted down my firewall with

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

This is my docker compose file:
This nginx folder is a copy from a init boot of another nginx container.

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 90:90
    container_name: my-nginx
    environment:
      TZ: Asia/Shanghai
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/nginx:/etc/nginx
```

This is my nginx configure file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';


    log_format  more  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                      '"$proxy_host" $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for - "$scheme"';


    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


    upstream test {
        # zone upstream_dynamic 64k;
        server 192.168.111.64:8080;
        # server backend1.example.com      weight=5;
        # server backend2.example.com:8080 fail_timeout=5s slow_start=30s;
        # server 192.0.2.1                 max_fails=3;
        # server backend3.example.com      resolve;
        # server backend4.example.com      service=http resolve;

        # server backup1.example.com:8080  backup;
        # server backup2.example.com:8080  backup;
    }

    server{
        listen 80;
        server_name  192.168.39.7;
        location / {
            #proxy_set_header Host $remote_addr;
            #proxy_pass http://192.168.111.64/quince-builds;
            access_log  /var/log/nginx/access-test.log  more;
            #return 702;
        }
        location /myrtle-builds{
            proxy_pass http://192.168.111.63/myrtle-builds;
        }
        location /quince-builds{
            proxy_pass http://192.168.111.64/quince-builds;
        }
        location /qb{
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            #proxy_pass http://192.168.111.64/quince-builds;
            return 701;
        }
        location /push{
            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            #proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.111.64:8080/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=quince-cloud-push;
        }
        location = /pushtest{
            client_body_buffer_size     10M;
            #client_max_body_size        10M;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.32.177:9898/report/update_data;
        }
         location ~* /icons{
            # When request /icons*******, proxy to /usr/share/icons*****
            root /usr/share;
            #proxy_pass http://192.168.39.7;
            access_log  /var/log/nginx/access-test.log  more;
        }
    }



}
```

Not sure if this helps:

```
root@7f21cf089c06:/# nginx -q
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [emerg] 53#53: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [emerg] 53#53: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [notice] 53#53: try again to bind() after 500ms
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [emerg] 53#53: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [emerg] 53#53: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [notice] 53#53: try again to bind() after 500ms
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [emerg] 53#53: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [emerg] 53#53: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [notice] 53#53: try again to bind() after 500ms
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [emerg] 53#53: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [emerg] 53#53: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [notice] 53#53: try again to bind() after 500ms
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [emerg] 53#53: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [emerg] 53#53: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [notice] 53#53: try again to bind() after 500ms
2023/03/21 08:03:04 [emerg] 53#53: still could not bind()
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

I tried to rm the container and run a simple nginx container by doing:

```
docker run -dit -p 80:80 nginx
```

When I request http://192.168.39.7, it still redirect to http://192.168.39.7/quince-builds.

And when I changed the port it works and I can see the "Welcome to nginx" page by doing:

```
docker run -dit -p 81:80 nginx
request http://192.168.39.7:81
```

This is the port using after I removed the nginx container:

```
[tcnsh@localhost nginx-test]$ sudo netstat -anp |grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3785/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      3792/docker-proxy
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     57863    3808/containerd-shi  /run/containerd/s/2ec67cbd3cf0a5e172513d980e4ec1174e571a4b29c2b62d655411eb810fae87
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     29880    1327/containerd      /run/containerd/containerd.sock.ttrpc
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     30080    2683/gsd-keyboard
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     52010    3808/containerd-shi  /run/containerd/s/2ec67cbd3cf0a5e172513d980e4ec1174e571a4b29c2b62d655411eb810fae87
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    8680     956/python2
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     62481    3808/containerd-shi
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     49380    2647/boltd
```

This is the access-test.log after I recreate a new container and copy the config file:

```
root@6f5dff3c80f6:/etc/nginx# cat /var/log/nginx/access-test.log
192.168.32.186 - - [21/Mar/2023:17:15:32 +0800] "GET /icons/blank.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://192.168.39.7/quince-builds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-" "-" 192.168.32.186 - "http"
192.168.32.186 - - [21/Mar/2023:17:15:32 +0800] "GET /icons/back.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://192.168.39.7/quince-builds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-" "-" 192.168.32.186 - "http"
192.168.32.186 - - [21/Mar/2023:17:15:32 +0800] "GET /icons/folder.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://192.168.39.7/quince-builds/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-" "-" 192.168.32.186 - "http"
```

Nginx logs:

```
192.168.32.186 - - [21/Mar/2023:17:15:32 +0800] "GET /quince-builds/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2642 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.3
6" "-"
2023/03/21 17:15:32 [error] 61#61: *4 open() "/usr/share/icons/blank.gif" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.32.186, server: 192.168.39.7, request: "GET /icons/blank.gif HTTP/1.1", ho
st: "192.168.39.7", referrer: "http://192.168.39.7/quince-builds/"
2023/03/21 17:15:32 [error] 61#61: *3 open() "/usr/share/icons/back.gif" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.32.186, server: 192.168.39.7, request: "GET /icons/back.gif HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.39.7", referrer: "http://192.168.39.7/quince-builds/"
2023/03/21 17:15:32 [error] 61#61: *4 open() "/usr/share/icons/folder.gif" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.32.186, server: 192.168.39.7, request: "GET /icons/folder.gif HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.39.7", referrer: "http://192.168.39.7/quince-builds/"
```

By the way, I wonder if this is a docker network issue, so I tried to restart the docker service and reboot the linux host.

Comment: First of all, port `80` is in use by another process, so you should change to another not-in-use port like `8080`. After it worked correctly, please share `access.log` with the request that has been made.

Comment: Hi @Andromeda. Just edited my question. As mentioned, I tried to check the 80 port and I can not see there is any process have taken port `80`.  I have lost access.log, so I have to recreate the container and send the request in my browser: `http://192.168.39.7`.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think the Nginx has no problem. It shows the 'welcome to Nginx' page when I tried to use another machine to send the request. So after a massive cleanup of my google chrome and I can successfully got the right page!